# Where is my background image coming from?

Tags: ios, xcode, default.png

Note that I'm new to IOS and Xcode, so this may be a silly question.
I'm working on a large existing app, adding Retina Display support. (xcode 4.5.1)

The apps starts up, does it's logon screen, then displays the "Default.png" as the background for the app.
Note that I DO have a "Default-586h@2x.png" file - which is NOT displayed at any time as far as I can tell.

I have modified our code to detect screen size and position windows accordingly.  That works.
In the IPhone 6 emulator, 4" Retina display, the background image is letterboxed.
I haven't been able to figure out how to make it use the correct background image.
There is only 1 reference to Default.png in the system, and that is in the RootScreenController.xib, which is referenced from the MainWindow.xib.  Opening those with XCode, I haven't been able to find ANY setting that directly references Default.png.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have a Default.png, a Default@2x.png and a Default-568h@2x.png copied to your app bundle. So if they are all members of your target, you are fine. They don't need to be referenced anywhere.

Edit:
Also you have to create your window in the right way to let the app have the appropiate size. How do you create your main window?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made a typo, it should be "Default-568h@2x.png".

Comment: @CasaDelGato - Correct the typo in the question then.

Answer (score 0):

i Recommend changing the images in your app that look like that background.

(replacing them with images that are black or blue or another solid color should suffice)

**NOTE** save them somewhere first so you can put them back.

Then when you determine the offending image. press Command+Shift+F and search for that filename. If that does not help. they may be set in the xib file somewhere. a quick switch to code compare mode via the "Version Editor" will let you search the text of the xib file.

search in there for the offending filename.

If it is the background of your app. it is definitely being set somewhere.

Comment: I've proven (by editing it) that the Default.png is what is being displayed in my app background.  In my original question, I noted that the only reference found was in a xib, and that I haven't found ANY way to change it in the XCode editor.   "RootScreenView.xib:       <string key="NSResourceName">Default.png</string>" is where it's found.

Comment: We did eventually find a reference to a reference to a reference that had the png name.  Royal PITA to find it.